# Permission granted in etc/sudoers only lasts for 10 minutes

Tags: php, unix, sudoers

I have a PHP script which contains a `shell_execute()` and the command it executes normally requires sudo. I've edited the sudoers with visudo to contain the following:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/root/node/npm/node_modules/less/
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/root/node/npm/node_modules/less/
```

I suspect either should work, but I went with the belt-and-suspenders approach to be sure.

I'm editing etc/sudoers with vim, so after adding these lines, I do :x and everything works. My PHP script does what it's supposed to... for about 10-15 minutes. Then the script stops working. Specifically, the `shell_exec()` stops working.

If I do `sudo visudo` again, my new lines are still there. But only when I save it again does the script start working again.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening? I have two guesses that aren't very good:

1. There is some sort of grace period that starts when I `sudo visudo` and this is what's allowing my script to work (but only until it expires).
2. The new data in etc/sudoers is staying in sudoers.tmp (the "Lock file")...
   Neither of these add up to me.

Comment: This sounds like a server admin problem to me. Maybe serverfault.com would be a better place to ask this?

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like you're trying to run node.js to compile your less styles into CSS? If that's the case, might I suggest some sort or CI server like [CIJoe](https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe) or [Travis](http://travis-ci.org)

Comment: @adlawson: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. However those server setups appear to be over my head. I'm currently running MAMP.

Comment: @Emerson might I suggest: http://thechangelog.com/post/14041353400/watch-simple-periodical-execution-utility-in-c

Comment: @James Butler: I looked at the link but I couldn't figure out how it solves my problem. Can you give me a little context for what that is or why it's useful?

Comment: @Emerson: It's basically a little cron program that will run commands for you every $timeInterval, I and many others use it along with Make for autobuilding stuff like compiled CSS, coffee-script etc. Check out the readme.md for it: https://github.com/visionmedia/watch. I found it cleaner and more awesome than cli php scripts (once i got my head around using Make in a sane fashion), give it a shot, your ninja powers will increase ten fold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) in the PHP docs, this will work.

```
system('echo "PASS" | sudo -u root -S COMMAND');
```

I have not tested it.

Comment: I've seen this but those same comments acknowledge that this is very insecure. It means that secret passwords are floating around in the files.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:

[Increase sudo time before you need to type password again](http://forum.foresightlinux.org/index.php?topic=504.0)

Happy sudoing :D

Comment: That's a nice trick but it doesn't solve me problem. My PHP script shouldn't be getting asked for a password ever.